# Removing certain hours in day from time series over several yearsv - python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dateframe containing a hourly data over 15 years. Now I would like to reduce this data to keep only the daylight hours from 6am-8pm and get rid of all the other rows. What is the best approach to do this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
print(df['date_time'].dtype)
df_only_daytime = df.drop(df[[df['date_time'].hour < 6]], axis=0)
```

The output is:

```
datetime64[ns]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-a4e1fe6a71b4> in <module>
      1 print(df['date_time'].dtype)
----> 2 df_only_daytime = df.drop(df[[df['date_time'].hour < 6]], axis=0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can take a look at this example:

```py
df.loc[(df['date_time'].dt.hour >= 6) & (df['date_time'].dt.hour <= 8)] # Add dt in front to get the hour
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! 
Is there also a way that the current date is not added when I use dt.hour?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by not adding the current date?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with something else I'd done earlier. All good! Thanks for your help!